# Is an old pid reused at any point?

Tags: linux, pid

A very elementary question:
I observed that the PID given to new process keeps increasing. As of now when I typed `ps` the pid of `ps` is given as 48564. (when i do `ps` again it gets a +1 value)

The limit given in the file `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` is 65536.

So what would happen if I reach this limit. Are the PIDs of terminated processes reused ?

Comment: [This](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26677/will-process-ids-be-recycled-what-if-you-reach-the-maximal-id) and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/135007/how-are-pids-generated) are all you need. Strange you didn't find them upon Google search.

Comment: yep.. my bad.. i should have looked more thoroughly.. please close it.

Answer (score 8):

Yes of course they are reused.  Some systems run for years, and every one of those 65K PIDs will be recycled thousands of times, except for the first few which are "special."